# Storing non-json data into a column with type not NVARCHAR(MAX), which is used for a JSON property index, throws an error

Tags: json, sql-server

I've a problem storing non-json data into a column which is used for a [JSON property index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/index-json-data?view=sql-server-ver16). **After the index has been created**, storing non-json data into the column results in the following error: `[S0001][13609] Line 1: JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character 'n' is found at position 0.`

I've created the computed column needed for the index and the index itself like this:

```
ALTER TABLE foo ADD vBar AS IIF(ISJSON(DETAILS_JSON) > 0, JSON_VALUE(DETAILS_JSON, '$.bar'), NULL)
CREATE INDEX IDX_FOO_BAR_ID ON foo (vBar)
```

When trying to store non-json data in the column (e.g. `UPDATE foo SET bar = 'simple text'`) it results in the error mentioned above.

However, when I execute the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/index-json-data?view=sql-server-ver16) and store non-json data in the column it works...

Comment: Seems like a bug in SQL Server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1009460/storing-non-json-data-into-a-column-with-type-varc.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the length of the column where the JSON data is stored. The length has to be `MAX` - if it is different (e.g. `NVARCHAR(4000)` or `VARCHAR(4000)`) it results in the mentioned error.

I. e. the type of the column has to be `NVARCHAR(MAX)` or `VARCHAR(MAX)`.